# Implementing a full-text search software into a library website

Tags: php, curl, full-text-search

I'm running a website that gives access to certain documents within my organisation. Currently searching may only be ran based on documents' name. I'd like to improve that by implementing a full-text search software, such as Archivarius 3000. It also has a feature that allows to use it online.

The problem is that my website and Archivarius are actually different sites. How do I give access to Archivarius only for logged in users of my site? How do I remove from Archivarius' search results documents that are not allowed for certain users?

As I see it, there should be a chain, such as this: search_form on my site, handler that redirects requests to Archivarius (PHP's cURL or something like that), handler that filters search results and shows them on my website.

I guess there might be problems with sessions.

Am I guessing things right? Anything else I have to keep in mind?

Answer (score 0):

In general, full-text search is added to a site by scanning the database directly and indexing what you have - not scraping data using a crawler. The simplest incarnation of this is a loop that runs through every document and sends it to the indexer. If you have a lot of documents, it is worth doing an initial full index and then only re-indexing documents individually when you detect it has changed.

As for user access, this is something that needs to be recorded in the indexer. Authorisation is usually done in groups, so a document that may be seen by "sales" and "managers" has that metadata sent to the indexer. When performing a search, your search form should add the group(s) to which they belong as meta items, so that search results they cannot access anyway are not shown.

If you plan to use the specific software you've mentioned, you may need to consult the manual that comes with that product. However, there are plenty of other ways to do it: consider [Zend's Lucene](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.9/en/zend.search.lucene.html) implementation, as well as the full text index systems in MySQL and PostgreSQL.